# Is there any way to print image name from PhotoImage in tkinter without storing image name anywhere else?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, chess

I am trying to print image name as output from tkinter photo button. Mainly without storing the image file name anywhere else. Looking for a way to directly pick image file name from PhotoImage.

Code I am trying:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def clicked(square):
    name = square.image_name
    print(name)

root = Tk()

white = "#f2f2f2"
black = "#555555"

# Create button with image
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("pawn_black.png").resize((50, 50), Image.LANCZOS))
a7_button = Button(root, bg=black, image=photo, command=lambda:clicked(a7_button))
a7_button.image = photo
a7_button.place(x=20,y=80)

root.mainloop()
```

- Output I am getting: `pyimage1`
- Output I am expecting: `pawn_black.png`

Storing like this works: `a7_button.image_name = "pawn_black.png"`

But, I want a way to pick file name directly from this link `Image.open("pawn_black.png")` by some way. I am searching for this to update chess piece image from one box to another from getting its current box image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to wrap a function so that an argument can be provided before that function is called.

If you redefine `clicked` as follows:

```
def clicked(file_name):
    print(file_name)
```

Then you can define the button like this:

```
a7_button = Button(root, bg=black, image=photo, command=partial(clicked, 'pawn_black.png'))
```

It is not possible to obtain the file name from the `ImageTk.PhotoImage` itself.  The [`PhotoImage`](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/main/src/PIL/ImageTk.py) class does not store a reference to the PIL `Image` object that was used to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping you adding a new member variable (e.g. containing a filename) to an object dynamically.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def clicked(square):
    name = square.sourceFilename
    print(name)

root = Tk()

white = "#f2f2f2"
black = "#555555"

# Create button with image
filename = "pawn_black.png"
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename).resize((50, 50), Image.LANCZOS))
a7_button = Button(root, bg=black, image=photo, command=lambda:clicked(a7_button))
a7_button.image = photo
a7_button.sourceFilename = filename       <--- HERE
a7_button.place(x=20,y=80)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Or maybe you mean this:

```
im = Image.open('pawn_black.png')
print(im.filename)
```